# Retrieving data with the help of intent-filter

Tags: android, intentfilter

In my application, I have an intent-filter registered for one of my activities. When I click on a number in sms/e-mail, dialog is displayed whether I want to call though the standard dial of my phone of though the activity with intent-filter. What I want to do is not just open a particular activity, but also retrieve the number, that was clicked. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Ok, I found the number in data. The uri data String was "tel:<some_number>", so I could easily retrieve the clicked number.

Answer (score 0):

add the relative info while initializing your intent and then broadcast it.
for example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:000000000"));
```

where 000000000 is your desired telephone number which may take out from any selected view

Comment: Thaks, Waqas. But I don't initialize an intent, I just have an intent-filter.

Answer (score 0):

use **intent.putExtra("key", "value")** to set phone number in your intent before sending it, and at receiving side take this value out from your received intent